Does cvc5 have a way to understand an SMTLIB string with its Python api? (Something like Z3's .from_string())
In z3, you can do this:
from z3 import Solver

s = Solver()

s.from_string("""
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)

(assert (> x 2))
(assert (< y 10)) 
(assert (= (+ x y) 7))
""")

s.check()
s.model() # returns [y = 0, x = 7]

Is there a way to pass an SMTLIB formatted string to cvc5 in Python and get check satisfiability and get a model?
The documentation says that SMT2 file parsing is not supported which leads me to believe that string parsing probably wouldn't be supported either.

I'm pretty sure it's not supported. You can ask at https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/discussions and they're quite responsive. Please update this post with what you find out if you do so.

https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/discussions/10454 suggests perhaps this is now supported from C++. (Details are a bit murky.) Not sure if Python has the same facility.
